# How do I make a list(array) of functions from np.poly1d in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

I'm running through some tiffs that represent the amount of water being evaporated. My code below loops through the images and makes a polynomial function for each pixel.However, after poly_fn is appended to list z, only the coefficients are being appended. Can anyone recommend a solution for the functions to be stored as well in list z? List z must have 351 rows and 308 columns. I attached the tif files in a zip folder.

```
import os
import glob
import arcpy
import numpy as np

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = r'E:\Alcalde\Scratch'
Scratchws = r'E:\Alcalde\Scratch\\'

KC_list = glob.glob(r'E:\Alcalde\Kc\*.tif')

KC_array = []
dates = []



for KC_tiff in KC_list:
    name = os.path.basename(KC_tiff).split(".")[0]
    date = os.path.basename(name).split("_")[2]
    date = float(date[-3:])

    KC_arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(KC_tiff)
    KC_array.append(KC_arr)
    shape = numpy.shape(KC_arr)
    date_arr = np.full(shape, date)
    dates.append(date_arr)

z = []

for row in range(0, 351):
    for column in range(0,308):
        x = []
        y = []
        for img in range(0,43):
            pixel = KC_array[img][row][column]
            date = dates[img][row][column]

            x.append(dates[img][row][column])
            y.append(KC_array[img][row][column])
        print("Pixel (Row, Column): " + str(row) + "," + str(column))
        poly = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
        poly_fn = np.poly1d(poly)

        z.append(poly_fn)
        print(poly_fn)
        print("====================================")


w = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in z])
q = np.reshape(w, (351, 308, 4))

print(q[350][307])
print("Complete..")
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B98EBGPvI6yvRE5FUHJXWkZlZHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `z` should be a list of `poly1d` objects.  What are you trying to do with `w`?  `np.array(xi)` is a 4 element array of the coefficients of one `poly1d`.  You are not making an array of `poly1d` objects.  Show us, with just one `poly1d` object what you are trying to do, and explain why.  What do you hope to do with array once you've got it?

Comment: Thanks! So how would I make z a list of poly1d objects? Each poly1d object is a function for each pixel (y is a crop coefficient and x represents the day of year). This is pretty much an interpolation. I want to be able to make an array of poly1d objects and then run a for loop for each day of the year.

Comment: `z` is a list of those objects.  We could an object dtype array that would hold the same pointers.  But why not loop through `z` itself?

Comment: Why don't you save `z` as a nested list, a list of 351 sublists?  You could access it `z[i][j]`.  You aren't using the array style indexing `w[i, j]` anyways, so  you don't lose anything by sticking with lists.  Trying to use object arrays will just complicate things, especially if the concept is new to you.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks mate! listing through z itself made the code work exactly as it is meant to. I guess I just didn't know I could loop through z itself.